# Update state in parent from slot in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, slot

I'm new to Vue and am currently stuck on a problem. I use Vuetify in my project and I have a v-dialog component with a slot like this:

```
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="600px">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn class="ma-3" color="info" v-on="on">{{ text }}</v-btn>
      </template>
      <slot></slot>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-row>
</template>
```

In this component i will pass a form as the slot, and i want to be able to close the modal when i submit the form. Coming from a React background I would simply pass a function that would set the dialog variable to false when i submit the form in the slot. I can't figure out how this is best done in Vue. The examples i find when i google seems too excessive and over-complicated for such an easy operation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read more about slot scope [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html),

> That slot has access to the same instance properties (i.e. the same “scope”) as the rest of the template.

Since, you are passing your `form` via `slot`, you would already be having the access to the `parent` component instance.

Also, as mentioned in the docs, its good to remember

> Everything in the parent template is compiled in parent scope; everything in the child template is compiled in the child scope.

So, when you write your component,

```
<template>
  <ModalComponent>
    <form @submit="toggleModalVisibility"> 
      ...
    </form>
  </ModalComponent>
</template>
```

any method passed to `form` will have access to `state` of the parent component.

Now, if you can just set a data property to toggle the visibity of the modal component in the parent and a method to toggle this property

```
data: () => {
  return {
    showModal: false //or true
  }
},
methods: {
  toggleModalVisibility() {
    this.showModal = !this.showModal;
  }
}
```

You can just assign this method to onSubmit handler of the form

```
form @submit="toggleModalVisibility"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent to close the dialog, then you should (probably) also make the parent responsible for opening the dialog. Otherwise, you can end up with components fighting each other for control.

That's easy enough to do. Have the parent pass a property to your custom component that enables or disables the dialog. Since the parent is also providing the form as a slot, the parent can handle events from that form and set the property correctly.